# How long can a shield/block that belongs to Ganondorf last against an aggresive Little Mac?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

In all Super Smash Bros Titles, players can block. When they block, the player gets a bubble (shield) around them that absorbs damage and even reflects some attacks. But, if a player holds it for too long, or takes too much damage, the shield will pop and they will be stunned for a considerable amount of time. What precentage of damage does it take for Ganon's shield to break?

It would be with no items and no custom (for Glory).

Comment: I think this is a bit too broad as it stands, between all the characters, attacks, and items. The shield behaves different. If you edited it to a single matchup it would be better.

Comment: Oh, each character has a different sheild %?

Comment: I'm not certain about that (it's a feeling), but I do know various attacks do much more damage to the shield than the player EX: [Lucina hs a shield breaker](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Shield_Breaker).

Comment: I reformated the question so it is not as broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shields](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Shield) have 50 HP, regardless of character. However, this is slightly misleading for two reasons:

1. Shields take 0.7x damage from most attacks.
2. If an attack has increased [shield damage](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Shield_damage), the additional damage is not reduced to 0.7x.

So while a value of ~70 HP is probably more practical, stuff like floor attacks, Shield Breaker, Eruption, and Mr. Saturn will have a much more destructive effect.

Comment: Ohh, I was originally asking for the asking about how much HP shields had, but there must have been a misunderstanding.